# How do you structure callbacks to build a complex single-page sign up form?

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, callback

I am building a single-page signup form that has 3 parts:

1. Username & password (for authentication)
2. Profile info (no auth required)
3. Credit card info (3rd party service)

So, callbacks are critical here as the data needs to be processed in three different ways and I can't figure out how to structure them so that they will fire in the right order.

registration-controller.js

```
var userController = require('../controllers/user-controller');

exports.postSignup = function(req, res, next){

  if (errors) {
    // error handling
  }
  passport.authenticate('signup', { // --Needs to run first
    successRedirect: '/dashboard', // --Needs to run 4th
    failureRedirect: '/signup',
    failureFlash : true
  })(req, res, next);


usersController.postProfile; // --Needs to run 2nd
usersController.postBilling; // --Needs to run 3rd
};
```

How do you structure these callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

`passport.authenticate` takes callback parameter which can be used to call your 2nd and 3rd actions. But then it's your responsibility to manually login user and redirect or flash any error messages. Here is a basic example. But you can always see the [source](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/middleware/authenticate.js) to see how the redirect and flash messages are handled by default.

```
passport.authenticate('signup', function(err, user, info){  // --Needs to run first
    if(err) return next(err)

    //authentication failed
    if(!user){
        return res.redirect('/signup');
    }

    usersController.postProfile; // --Needs to run 2nd
    usersController.postBilling; // --Needs to run 3rd

    req.logIn(user, options, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/dashboard');  // --Needs to run 4th
    })
})(req, res, next);
```